# Php global application variable storage to select folder

Tags: php, file, variables, upload, global

I am working on an application which has thousands of file uploads from  different users.
In the server, each folder holds only 1 lakh files and hence we created 15 different folders so that we can upload to each of this folders in order (in rotation).

To accomplish this, there should be a global application variable across  all the users to track the folder to which last upload take place. How can I accomplish this?

I develop the application  Windows and my server is Linux. So how can I accomplish this task in both of the machines?

Thanks
M

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly...

You can write it into the RAM (memcached), or into the database (memory table if available).

The alternative approach would be to save files based on their id if they have one, so you can calculate where the file's place is instead of rotating the directories.